# Assign true to all variable except one

Tags: z3, solver, smt, z3py, sat

I have a list of variables and I want to add constraint to z3 solver such as all variables should be False except one variable should be True ..

```
a,b,c,d= Bool('a,b,c,d')
s = Solver()
allvariables=[a,b,c,d,f] 
for i in allvariables:
     s.add(i==True)
```

Do I need to use Quantifier ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @alias, there are alternative encodings of the exactly-one [cardinality constraints](https://www.carstensinz.de/papers/CP-2005.pdf).

The `Sum()` function makes life easy:

```py
    from z3 import *
    
    a, b, c, d = Bools('a b c d')
    allvariables = [a, b, c, d]
    s = Solver()
    
    #  exactly one
    s.add(Sum(allvariables) == 1)
    
    res = s.check()
    sol_no = 0
    while (res == sat):
      m = s.model()
      block = []
      sol_no += 1
      print(f"Solution #{sol_no}")
      for var in allvariables:
          v = m.evaluate(var, model_completion=True)
          print("%s = %s " % (var, v)),
          block.append(var != v)
      s.add(Or(block))
      print("")
      res = s.check()
```

Result are four solutions as expected:

```
Solution #1
a = False 
b = False 
c = True 
d = False 

Solution #2
a = False 
b = True 
c = False 
d = False 

Solution #3
a = False 
b = False 
c = False 
d = True 

Solution #4
a = True 
b = False 
c = False 
d = False
```

Comment: `Sum` trick is cute; but I never liked the coercion in there. Treating a boolean as a number to be summed up is just unsafe. There was even an issue reported (https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/6598) which shows how relying on such coercions can lead to inscrutable error messages, and even bugs if it "just happens to work." I'd advise against using `Sum` in this way.

Answer (score 2):

There's a variety of ways to code this constraint, but perhaps the easiest (and most performant) to use would be [PbEq](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#a248adcb0285dba41f357f3f77d170ccf):

```py
from z3 import *

a, b, c, d = Bools("a b c d")
allVars = [a, b, c, d]

s = Solver()
s.add(PbEq([(v, 1) for v in allVars], 1))

while s.check() == sat:
    m = s.model()
    print(m)
    s.add(Not(And(m[a] == a, m[b] == b, m[c] == c, m[d] == d)))
```

This prints:

```
[b = False, a = True, c = False, d = False]
[b = True, a = False, c = False, d = False]
[b = False, a = False, c = True, d = False]
[b = False, a = False, c = False, d = True]
```